# How the paint method run without in main method?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint

Here, we have two classes. One of them is application class.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx4fP.png]

[image]

And the output is a jframe which has a rectangular inside. But I don't get it, we don't write paint method in main method. How can it run?

Comment: The `paint` method will be automatically call while the initialization of `JFrame`.

Comment: Paint method is in the Window class? Whatever, I debugged this application and I didn't see anything realtion with paint method.
I examined super constructor but none of them call the paint method.

Answer (score 2):

The paint method is automatically called to refresh your window. For example, the *paint* method is automatically called when resizing your window.

You can also force to call the paint method by calling the *repaint()* method of JFrame.

Also, if you're looking for the declaration of *paint* method, it is in *java.awt.Component*. Dont hesitate to have a look to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html)

Comment: I know it but I don't know how it Works. I mean if the frame refreshed which class or method call the paint method?

Comment: When resizing, your window manager will notify his listeners. In this case methods from *java.awt.Component* are called (resize, reshape, setBound, ...) and then Component will finally call paint(). I can't tell you which other classes calls paint, but it is one of them apparently.

Comment: You're welcome, do not forget to mark the problem as solved (if it is) and to take a look at the javadoc and the source code of awt and swing